# How to put a title onto Tableau Chart after it was removed

Tags: tableau-api

As shown in the screenshot the title `Price vs Distance to Work Hubs` was unintentionally displaced from the chart to .. *off* the chart .. So how can it be put back on the chart?  Drag/drop does not work..
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag your title between rows line and starting of worksheet as :

[image]

Comment: Clearly I prefer these features be available from the menu as well as the gui.  I find Tableau difficult to learn.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on **Worksheet**
2. Go to **Show Cards**
3. Click on **Reset Cards**

[image]

Comment: nice tip - looks like an alternative to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I found:

- Right click on the title area and select `Hide`
- On main menu: `Worksheet` and then select `Show title` :
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another approach for the same:

1.Right click on the area where Pages Shelf, Filter Shelf and Marks are appeared.

2.A menu appears, Click on **Reset Cards**

[image]